# DRY SQL store procedure; Very similar UPDATE statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a store procedure which I'm beginning to find hard to maintain. The aim is to update values in a `Stats` table with the values stored by Day, Month and Year.

This means I'm writing essentially the same `WHERE` clause 3 times, with only the date comparison part and corresponding DateType being different. Every time I need to change the where clause, I have to make the same change in 3 places. I have a lot of different stats and clients ask us to change them quite often. Here is my stats for male contacts created this day/month/year.

E.g:

```
UPDATE Stats
    SET Content = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contacts
                   WHERE Gender=1 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GetDate(), Created) = 0)
WHERE DateType = 1 AND StatType = 1

UPDATE Stats
    SET Content = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contacts
                   WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, GetDate(), Created) = 0)
WHERE DateType = 2 AND StatType = 1

UPDATE Stats
    SET Content = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contacts
                   WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, GetDate(), Created) = 0)
WHERE DateType = 3 AND StatType = 1
```

What I would like (but have no idea how to write) is some sort of store procedure where I can pass just once my clause, i.e `exec sp_updateStatsDayMonthYear 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contacts WHERE Gender=1'`.

Comment: If you want to call a stored procedure you might think about dynamic SQL, Why are you doing this? Why not get these values with a VIEW or a TVF on the fly? How many rows, how many new inserts are there?

Comment: @Shnugo We're doing this as there are about 25 stats, each to be done by day/month/year, and this numbers only going to keep getting bigger. It takes way too long to get these on the fly for the users (they're all more complicated than a count of users created today), so we're calculating them once every morning for the previous day.

Comment: One way is to use a calendar table. You join to your calendar table on Created, and the result is your data dropped into the appropriate buckets. You could put `DateType` into your calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using case statements:

```
UPDATE Stats
 SET   Content = case 
when 
DateType=1 AND StatType=1
then (select count(*) from contacts where DATEDIFF(DAY,GetDate(),Created)=0))
when 
DateType=2 AND StatType=1
then (select count(*) from contacts where DATEDIFF(DAY,GetDate(),Created)=0))
when 
DateType=3 AND StatType=1
then (select count(*) from contacts where DATEDIFF(DAY,GetDate(),Created)=0))
end
```

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: This has the same issue though. If I want to change it to all female contacts, I now need to change 3 clauses. *I updated my question to make this clearer*